# Segmentation fault the second time printf is called

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a simple C program that opens a file, and reads each line into an array, where LISTS is the maximum number of lines in the file that I wish to read.

However, when MASTER_LIST is less than LISTS lines long, I get a segmentation fault on printf() the second time round, but not the first (I've commented to show where).

I'm a little confused by this behaviour, and I'm wondering what causes it and what I can do to circumvent it. Ideally I would stop reading when fgets finds the end of the file.

```
#define MASTER_LIST "master_list.txt"
#define LINE 64
#define LISTS 32

char **lists = malloc(LISTS * sizeof(char *));
int i; 
for (i = 0; i < LISTS; i++) {
    lists[i] = malloc(LINE * sizeof(char));
}

/*Open the file for reading.*/
FILE *fp = fopen(MASTER_LIST, "r");
if (fp != NULL) {
    /*Each line of the file, up to LISTS is read into lists.*/
    for (i = 0; i < LISTS; i++){

        lists[i] = fgets(lists[i], LINE, fp);
        /*NO SEGFAULT HERE*/ printf("Line Read: %s\n", lists[i]);                   
    }
}

/*print out each line*/
for(i = 0; i < LISTS; i++){
    printf("Are we segfaulting yet? %d\n", i);
    /*HERE I GET A SEGFAULT*/ printf("%s\n", lists[i]);
    printf("How about now? %d\n", i);       
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the strings are properly terminated with a `'\0'` at the end?

Comment: I was under the impression that fgets added the null terminator automatically after any line endings. I'm sure that my textfile only has newline characters to separate lines.

Comment: have you tried running under valgrind?

Comment: The code does not take into account that `fgets()` will fail.  lists[i] is still assigned when fgets does fail. The code then tries to print out a NULL pointer - though not in the place I would expect.

Comment: Right, `fgets` returns `NULL` if there's an error or the end of file is reached with no characters read. So it _should_ already segfault in the first loop, unless `printf("%s")` handles null pointers gracefully.

Comment: Running this in gdb shows it really clearly: `/*HERE I GET A SEGFAULT*/ printf("%s\n", lists[i]);` / `(gdb) p lists[i] $4 = 0x0` (i.e. NULL) 
`(gdb) n Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`

Comment: @BertholtStutleyJohnson: Out of sheer curiosity: what compiler are you using? It may be a compiler optimization that causes the unusual output. (Remember, UB means anything goes).

Comment: Just good old-fashioned gcc.

Comment: Optimization flags? Do you see `(null)` being printed out by `printf`?

Comment: Yes, that's what prints out the first time around. No flags when I compiled, just turned on all warnings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fgets` returns `NULL` if it fails to read any characters, which would happen if your file contains less than `LISTS` lines. Attempting to `printf` a NULL pointer is undefined behaviour.

---

This is a good time to remind ourselves that undefined behaviour **really is** undefined. It looks like the `printf` should crash the *first* time around. But, the C spec says nothing about what *should* happen, so your `printf` just prints `(null)` (many Linux libcs do this, for example).

Why does the *second* `printf` crash, then? It's because you used the pattern

```
printf("%s\n", lists[i]);
```

Many compilers will optimize this to

```
puts(lists[i]);
```

and on your system, `puts` does **not** check for a NULL pointer and so it segfaults.

Moral of the story? Don't ever rely on undefined behaviour, or even expect consistent results.

Comment: So it might print the first time, and then segfault the next?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is like that sometimes. (Though, I will admit this is a bit weirder than normal).

Comment: The first time through it will have found the "end-of-file" marker, and just given you a NULL terminated string (which is good). It is when you try to read again after the end of file that `fgets` will return NULL and break things.

Comment: Both print statements occur after fgets has returned, however.

Comment: @BertholtStutleyJohnson: Got your explanation. Check out the answer now.